# How can I animate the color change of a shape drawn using CoreGraphics in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I have shapes drawn using CoreGraphics.

I'd like to animate the colour of the shape (I guess the `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor()`) from one colour, to another, over a period of a second.

Can anybody explain to me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Would you like to animate within a UIImageView?

Comment: Good explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809280/drawrect-circle-and-animate-size-color